# Prevent timeouts with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: php, apache, nginx, laravel, laravel-4

I'm experiencing timeouts when running a Job Queue listener (infinite while loop). The listener calls a worker whose function involves executing a software PhantomJS using `shell_exec()`.

I'm running nginx 1.2.7 with php5-fpm and PHP framework Laravel 4 (which uses symfony components).

**Problem:** After running for awhile, the listener will quit with the error `The process timed out`. I suspect it is due to the `shell_exec()` that takes a very long time to return its results.

[image]

**Attempts:** I tried increasing the timeouts settings on nginx to 600 seconds but that did not help. `set_time_limit(0)` does not help either.

How can you prevent it from timing out, or at least prevent the timing out error from killing the queue listener?

**sites-enabled/mysite.com**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com *.mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        client_body_timeout 600;
        send_timeout 600;
        proxy_read_timeout 600;
    }

}
```

**Error stacktrace**

```
exception 'Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'The process timed out.' in /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php:413
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/process/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.php(201): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->wait(NULL)
#1 /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php(63): Symfony\Component\Process\Process->run()
#2 /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php(50): Illuminate\Queue\Listener->runProcess(Object(Symfony\Component\Process\Process), 128)
#3 /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Queue/Console/ListenCommand.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\Listener->listen(NULL, 'default', 0, 128, 60)
#4 /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(108): Illuminate\Queue\Console\ListenCommand->fire()
#5 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php(240): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#6 /var/www/mysite/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php(96): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(193): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /var/www/mysite/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php(106): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/mysite/artisan(59): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#10 {main}
```

---

### Updates

Timeouts are still occuring when using Apache 2.2.22 and default settings. Any ideas what settings can be changed to avoid the timeouts?

Comment: Can you run this script whithout nginx?

Comment: @Victor Yes I am running the script in apache 2.2.22 instead of nginx 1.2.7 and timeouts are still occuring! Apache is running using the default settings. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not trying use timeouts in nginx. But I think it can be connected with php type running on nginx. In that use php loaded in memory and running more then 1 request and not unloaded after each request. It can be not saved use timeout becouse it can lead to get many system resourses. But it my IMHO. When I have spoke about "whithout nginx" I think about run your script in command line ore cron. Can you run script without any web server?

Comment: @Victor I can run using PHP without any webserver, eg: `php artisan queue:work` will run the script once. But the timeout occurs once every 1000-2000 runs, so I have never tested a thousand times manually to see it it still has timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Check #3. That function call has a very suspicious 60 as argument. Are you sure it's php limit you are hitting or is the code there listening for console output for max 60 seconds?

Comment: Referring to https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php#L35-44, that is the default timeout (imposed by the Queue listener) but not sure what it means...

Answer (score 0):

Once the `listen` process takes up too much memory, it kills itself.

```
if ($this->memoryExceeded($memory))
{
    $this->stop(); return;
}
```

I've heard you're supposed to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to ensure the process is restarted and always running. I'm not sure why you have to do this though /: and haven't tried it myself yet.